# echo a string with the first character is space

Tags: bash

I want echo a string which the first character is space, e.g. `line=" a"; echo $line;` However, the result is showing up without the first space, e.g. just `"a"` rather than `" a"`.

Comment: moral of bash -- "always quote your variables" :) http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html

Answer (score 3):

Just print it with double quotes around the name of the variable:

```
$ line=" a"
$ echo "$line"
 a
```

Comment: thanks, fedorqui. But actually, I want sed -i "3c $line" test.txt. but right now sed -i "3c "$line"" test.txt doesn't work giving error as "sed: -e expression #1, char 3: expected \ after `a', `c' or `i'"

Comment: @apple I think `sed -i "3c $line"`  is not a valid syntax at all. So what are you trying to do?

Comment: Please update your question with the code in it so we can read it properly. It is difficult to read the code in the comments

Comment: line=" a";sed -i "3c ${line}" test.txt. this is what I am using right now to change the line 3 of test.txt into  a. there is a space before letter a. what is the easiest way to do it then?

Comment: The best I can get is `sed -i "3c '$line'" test.txt`, but it is not enough. I suggest you to ask a new question with this sed code.